# Webservice to convert file to base64 string

Tags: json, web-services, base64

Is there a webservice available that will take a url of a file e.g. http://example.com/images/image.jpg and return a base64 encoded string of that file preferably in json format?

Comment: Does it need to be a webservice, or can it be implemented in a language to run locally?

Comment: It's doesn't need to be but I just wanted to know what was out there before doing it locally. Basically http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64 that as a webservice.

Comment: Very strange question. I don't see any need in such a strange webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to use this from?  Would something like this work?

`curl http://example.com/images/image.jpg | base64`